# given graph that vertices of 4 colors, find shortest path with at least 3 colors

Tags: algorithm

Given directed graph G where every vertice is colored with green,red, yellow or blue, and positive weights, find the shortest path from s to t that contains at least one red, one blue and one green node.

Please help me with this problem.

I try to expand the graph. each node has 4 different colors. I don't know if it is the right direction. Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Given graph that vertices of 3 colors , find the shortest path with the following coditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55689892/given-graph-that-vertices-of-3-colors-find-the-shortest-path-with-the-followin)

Answer (score 0):

There are the following color states of interest, ignoring nodes that have color yellow:

| not visited colors | visited colors |
| --- | --- |
| red, green, blue |  |
| green, blue | red |
| red, blue | green |
| red, green | blue |
| blue | red, green |
| green | red, blue |
| red | green, blue |
|  | red, green, blue |

So 8 color-states in total.

For each color state, create a duplicate of the graph . We could identify those with a subscript of three letters, where a capital means the corresponding color has been visited: , , , ..., .

Then for each red node in a graph  with a lowercase  in the subscript, add a directed edge with weight 0 to the same node in the other graph  that has the same subscript, except that it has an uppercase . Do a similar thing for blue and green nodes. So for instance a red node in  will have an edge to the same node in G.

Now use a standard Dijkstra algorithm on this extended graph, starting with node  in  to node  in .